# Can't see the source of an error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to locate a bug (in my dev environment) that is preventing a successful form submission. Instead of the usual helpful error screen I'm used to seeing, I'm getting an unhelpful 404 screen.  Tailing development.log shows me nothing except the parameters sent with the form and that the response was a 404. How can I see what's really going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails does a pretty good job about bubbling this sort of stuff up - are you not catching it somewhere and swallowing the error along the way?

My first suggestion would be to fire up script/console and emulate your controller code (assuming you're just working with models) and see what happens.